# How to return to the corresponding udp sender after the socks5 proxy - Windows lsp spi udp

Tags: proxy, udp, winsock-lsp

I use windows lsp for proxy some url and game UDP over local sock5 proxy.

I have a problem with it: How to get caller port in function: `int WSPAPI WSPSendTo`?

I want to follow the following steps:

- 1: connection to local proxy server over TCP
- 2: get local proxy server opened UDP port
- 3: send UDP data with function `NextProcTable.lpWSPSendTo`
- 4: recv data
- 5: Forward received data to the UDP caller

but can't work out the last one. How to forward received data to the UDP caller?

Comment: Now the problem has been solved! After send data in step 3, log the code of socket recv and local udp sender; when caller call function recvFrom : recv data from local sender udp , use memcpy copy data to udp caller !

Comment: emm! how to close the question